# Turning Angular factory into ES6 class service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, es6-class

I am trying to rewrite an angular factory into a fat arrow function, but really struggling with this as haven't done much in ES6, so any guidance is appreciated.

Here's my existing code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngResource from 'angular-resource';

export default angular
     .module('FlightService', [ngResource])
     .factory('FlightService', $resource => {
  'ngInject';

  const apiUrl = 'https://murmuring-ocean-10826.herokuapp.com/en/api/2';

  return $resource('', {}, {
       getAirportData: { method: 'GET', url: `${apiUrl}/forms/flight-booking-selector` },
       queryFlights: { method: 'GET', url: `${apiUrl}/flights/from/:departure/to/:destination/:startDate/:endDate/250/unique` },
  });
 }).name;
```

expected outcome:

```
export const FlightService = () => {
    // missing code
}
```

My attempt was as follows:

```
export const FlightService = () => {
    'ngInject';
    constructor($resource) {

    const apiUrl = 'https://murmuring-ocean-10826.herokuapp.com/en/api/2';
    var FlightService = $resource('', {}, {
        getAirportData: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${apiUrl}/forms/flight-booking-selector` 
        },
        queryFlights: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${apiUrl}/flights/from/:departure/to/:destination/:startDate/:endDate/250/unique`
        },
    });
    return FlightService;
   }
}
```

This doesn't work, I get an unexpected token error at this mustache:

```
constructor($resource) {
```

Any help greatly appreciated as it's had me stuck for the last couple of hours.

Comment: What do you want the arrow function to return, the `FlightService`? Then drop that `constructor` altogether!

Comment: `$resource` should probably be the parameter of that arrow functions